# Prepared statment using arrays and temp table

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, temp-tables

I am have this temporary table statement:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) AS name, UNNEST(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']) AS col2;
```

From which I am trying to create a prepared statement. As far as I can make out from the Postgres docs, the below should work, but I am getting the below error.

```sql
PREPARE createTempTable(int[], text[]) AS
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
    SELECT UNNEST($1) AS col1, UNNEST($2) AS col2;
EXECUTE createTempTable(ARRAY[1, 2, 3], ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: PREPARE createTempTable(int[], text[]) AS CREATE TEMP TABLE ...
```

Comment: This is not allowed, you can't use PREPARE on DDL, like creating a (temp) table. Executing this statement more than once, would result in an error anyway.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you, greatly appreciated. Is it allowed to use PREPARE on CTEs? I'm building a web application and all our queries are prepared statments since they need to use parameters. I had add a lot of temporary tables and CTEs to a large SQL file to reduce code duplication but it seems I'm going to have to strip it all out and just accept the duplicaiton.

Comment: Yes, you can prepare a CTE, just give it a try. You could also put your complex SQL into VIEWs and FUNCTIONs, and prepare these. And personally I almost never use temporary tables, in my work there is always a better solution.